# Ler linhas e colunas mescladas no excel, usando python

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, xls

Estou tendo dificuldade para ler as informações de uma planilha que tem linhas e colunas mescladas. Eu tentei usar merged_cell para obter o valor, mas eu não entendo como ele funciona. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Usando o script abaixo, eu posso obter os valores, **exceto** para as células mescladas. Como posso obter todas as células, inclusive os mesclados?

```
from xlrd import open_workbook,cellname

workbook = open_workbook('file.xls')
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

for row_index in range(sheet.nrows):       
for col_index in range(sheet.ncols):    

print cellname(row_index,col_index),'-',    
print sheet.cell_value(row_index,col_index)
```

Comment: Seu problema é que as células mescladas não dão valor nenhum, ou que só uma delas (topo-esquerda) dá algum valor?

Comment: Oi, tenho uma tabela 515x258. Tenho por exemplo cinco colunas mescladas, e dentro de mescla tenho 2 linhas. A primeira linha é normal e na segunda linha tem 4 colunas mescladas. COnsegue visualizar mentalmente? De todas essas linhas e colunas, eu recebo valor de: algumas células que estão mescladas e não recebo nenhum valor de célula não-mesclada. Sendo que todas as céluas contém valores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O funcionamento do [`merged_cells`](http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html#xlrd.Sheet.merged_cells-attribute) é o seguinte: cada entrada nessa lista contém 4 valores - a primeira linha (topo), a última linha, a primeira coluna (esquerda) e a última coluna. Essas linhas e colunas formam um retângulo. Nos dados da planilha, somente a célula superior esquerda possui dados e formatação, as demais aparecem como se estivessem em branco.

Uma maneira de mapear todas as células para o seu valor de fato seria então o seguinte:

```
from collections import defaultdict
mescladas = defaultdict(lambda: '')

for crange in sheet.merged_cells:    # Para cada intervalo (conjunto de células mescladas)
    rlo, rhi, clo, chi = crange      # Descobre o "retângulo" que elas formam
    for rowx in range(rlo, rhi):     # Para cada linha
        for colx in range(clo, chi): # e cada coluna
            mescladas[(rowx,colx)] = sheet.cell_value(rlo, clo) # Copie o valor da célula
                                                                # superior esquerda

for row_index in range(sheet.nrows):
   for col_index in range(sheet.ncols):
       print cellname(row_index,col_index),'-',
       print sheet.cell_value(row_index,col_index) or mescladas[(row_index,col_index)]
```

Comment: Obrigada pela explicação tão detalhada, vou tentar aqui agora!

Comment: Oi, ele me retorna NameError: name 'thesheet' is not defined . Como eu o defino/declaro? Imaginei que fosse o nome da minha planilha, mas não é. Pode me orientar? Obrigada

Comment: @MaryTortugo Foi só um erro ao copiar o exemplo da documentação, o certo é usar `sheet` mesmo (que foi o nome que você deu pra variável). Corrigido

Comment: Deu Super Certo!! Muito obrigada!